# Probability of inequality with Chi-squared distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I want to evaluate analytically the following probability:

$P(X+XY\leq Z+ZW)$

where $X\thicksim \chi_1^2$, $Y\thicksim \chi_a^2$, $Z\thicksim \chi_1^2$, and $W\thicksim \chi_b^2$ with $a,b\geq 2$. All random variables are mutually independent.

Any idea on how to tackle it will be extremely welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the joint distribution of these variables this question cannot be answered. Assuming independence is one way to tell the joint distribution.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention the independence of the random variables. I will edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming that the random variables are independent of each other):

One can write $$P(X+XY\leq Z+ZW)=P\left(\frac{X}{Z}\leq \frac{1+W}{1+Y}\right)$$

The distribution of $\frac{X}{Z}$ can be found to be $F(1,1)$, since for $\chi^2$ distributed $X$ and $Z$, each with $k_1$ and $k_2$ degrees of freedom, $\frac{X/k_1}{Z/k_2}$ is $F(k_1,k_2)$ distributed.

One can find the distribution of $\frac{1+W}{1+Y}$ in a similar way. Let $T=\frac{1+W}{1+Y}\sim F_T$ and let $R=\frac{X}{Z}\sim F_R$

Then the question is to determine $$P(R\leq T)$$ from the distributions of $T$ and $R$. This probability can be obtained by

$$P \left[ R\leq T \right] = \int P \left[ R\leq t \right] f_T \left( t
   \right) \mathrm{d} t = \int F_R \left( t \right) f_T \left( t \right)
   \mathrm{d} t$$

Comment: you're welcome.